# Display Ports Dynamically in JointJs

Tags: jointjs, rappid

Is it possible to show ports programmatically in JoinJS? This is what I want to do.

- Using RappidJs.
- Would like to not show ports in Stencil.
- Show the ports after dropping cell on paper.

I see API for addPort and removePort but don't see anything around hide / display.

Comment: I have tried following but it has no effect.   cell.attr({
                '.joint-port': {
                    display: 'none',
                    visibility: 'hidden'
                },
                '.inPorts': {
                    display: 'none'
                },
                '.outPorts': {
                    display: 'none'
                }
            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try setting the port opacity attribute to show ports only after dropping to paper.

```
        attrs: {
                '.port-body': {
                    opacity: 1 // or 0
                }
```